# wkhtmltopdf - limit table of content child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I am using wkhtmltodpf along with knp-snappy and I am trying to limit TOC to max 3 childrens. I have defined custom xsl file which looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="outline:outline">
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
            <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="outline:item/outline:item"/></ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="outline:item">
    <li class="level-{count(ancestor::*) - 1}">
        <xsl:if test="((@title!='') and (@title!='Table of Contents'))">
            <div>
                <a>
                    <xsl:if test="@link">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@link"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@backLink">
                        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@backLink"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </a>
                <span> <xsl:value-of select="@page" /> </span>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
        <ul class="level-{count(ancestor::*) - 1}">
            <xsl:comment>added to prevent self-closing tags in QtXmlPatterns</xsl:comment>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="outline:item"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

and with output:

[image]

What I need to show only 1,2,3 levels
I'm not good into XML and I really don't know how could I limit it :/
I am using these tags to create my table of content:

1 - h4 tag
2 - h3 tag
3 - h2 tag
...

Comment: I don't see any `h2` or `h3` elements in the XSLT so I don't see where you create any of that structure you have inserted as an image. Show us the HTML you want to create. In general, if you know about the level at which you want to stop processing it shouldn't be to difficult to do that with e.g. `<xsl:template match="outline:item/outline:item/outline:item/outline:item"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen you can't see them because I am using wkhtmltopdf which creates PDF from give input. On of configuration file is xml to define how TableOfContent should look like

Answer (score 2):

solved by myself

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:outline="http://wkhtmltopdf.org/outline"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitiona
l.dtd"
                indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="outline:outline">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Table of Contents</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <style>
                    * {
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-seriff;
                    }

                    .book-toc-title {
                        margin-bottom: .5em;
                    }

                    .book-toc-list {

                    }

                    .book-toc-list .book-toc-list {

                    }

                    .book-toc-item {
                        list-style-type: none;
                    }

                    .book-toc-item .book-toc-item {
                        list-style-type: none;
                        list-style-position: outside;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        margin: 0.2em 0 0 2em;
                        padding-top: 0.2em;
                    }

                    .book-toc-item.level_1 {
                        padding-top: 0.5em;
                        margin-bottom: 0.2em
                    }
                    .book-toc-item.level_1:first-child {display: none;}
                    .book-toc-item.level_2 {padding-bottom: 0.2em;}
                    .book-toc-item.level_3 {}

                    .book-toc-item-inner {
                    }

                    .book-toc-item-title {
                    display: block;
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    }

                    .book-toc-item-title .text {
                    display: block;
                    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
                    height: 19px;
                    }

                    .book-toc-item-title .text-inner {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    line-height: 30px;
                    padding-right: 7px;
                    }

                    .book-toc-item .book-toc-item .book-toc-item-title {
                    font-weight: normal;
                    }

                    .book-toc-item-pagenum {
                    position: relative;
                    float: right;
                    top: 5px;
                    paddig-bottom: 0;
                    padding-left: 5px;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    text-align: right;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
                <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="outline:item/outline:item"/></ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="outline:item[count(ancestor::outline:item)&lt;=3]">
        <li class="book-toc-item level_{count(ancestor::outline:item)}">
            <xsl:if test="@title!=''">
                <div class="book-toc-item-inner">

                    <span class="book-toc-item-pagenum">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@page"/>
                    </span>

                    <a class="book-toc-item-title">
                        <xsl:if test="@link">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@link"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@backLink">
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@backLink"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <span class="text">
                            <span class="text-inner">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </xsl:if>

            <ol class="book-toc-list">
                <xsl:comment>added to prevent self-closing tags in QtXmlPatterns</xsl:comment>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="outline:item"/>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just to save everyone else some time - it's specifically this bit here that does the trick: `<xsl:template match="outline:item[count(ancestor::outline:item)&lt;=3]">`